# WebStorm 2017.3 logs me out each time I debug and double click the code

Tags: webstorm

Each time I debug my project in my new iMac 5k it logs me out. It doesn't restart it just logs me out. It's completely annoying I've tried OS restarts (of course), reinstalling WebStorm and even messing with vmoptions. The problem still happens.

It happens always only while debugging and I believe DOUBLE CLICKING AT THE SAME TIME ON THE CODE, but suddenly the machine logs me out.

My iMac has 24GB RAM I don't know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must be [WEB-31444](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31444), fixed in 2018.1. Please try the [Public Preview](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/nextversion/) - does it work?